# After long run ubuntu 14.04 is running slow

Tags: 14.04

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 and its running good. The problem is that if i run      machine more than 4 hours continuously then it become very slow. After then if i restart machine then it become normal. 
Previously i have installed 12.04 but i did not face  this kind of problem. 
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can not come in to a conclusion as Ubuntu 14.04 OS long run is the main cause of the issue. check memory usage and disk performance of the machine using the below command and check

**Memory usage checking during machine hang:**

```
cat /proc/meminfo
 you need to install htop
$ htop
FOr GUI level monitoring

System > Administration > System monitor:

watch -n 5 free -m
```

**Monitoring disk performance.**

```
dstat -D hda
sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sda

FOr GUI level monitoring

System -> Administration -> Disk Utility
```